# Create a calendar grid of the last 365 days

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, calendar

I am learning d3.js at the moment and I would like to create a calendar view that is similar to github Public contributions chart.

I am using this [d3.js calendar view](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) as my starting point.

The problem I'm having is trying to create a grid for the last 365 days. I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcR4Q/1/ with where I am stuck. At the moment it is just creating 365 boxes for a year range.

I think I need to change the following lines:

```
var svg = d3.select(".sales").selectAll("svg")
    .data(d3.range(2012, 2013))

...

return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
```

I've tried various things, but none have worked. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are modifying the original year (`today`) when setting the year for the previous one. Your code should look like this:

```
var today = new Date(),
lastyear = new Date();
lastyear.setFullYear(lastyear.getFullYear() - 1);
```

You don't actually need the nested selection here anymore because you only have a single year. So for the SVG, you only need to do

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("class", "RdYlGn")
.append("g")
.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

Finally, to compute the position of the cells, not the day/week is important anymore (as you want consecutive cells for the days), but the index:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return Math.floor(i / 7) * cellSize; })
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return i % 7 * cellSize; })
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fcR4Q/2/).

Comment: Thanks that is great. I would like them in date order and keep them positioned by day of the week. I have attempted this (see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcR4Q/3/)) but now the x-axis is offset by 3421233px! I'm trying to work out how I calculate the offset in this section `.attr("x", function(d) { return ((year(d)+week(d)) * cellSize); })`

Comment: This is slightly more tricky as you have to mess about with week offsets and such -- http://jsfiddle.net/fcR4Q/5/